# Can I detect OTA capability in Android?

Tags: android, ota

Is it possible to detect from an Android program, if an Android device is Over-the-Air provisionable?

Comment: You might wish to expand upon your question and explain exactly what you mean by "detect OTA in Android programmatically".

Comment: I want to detect if the handset is OTA(Over the Air) provisionable or not by an app(apk) using Android APIs..

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but this is not possible. There is nothing in Android SDK that knows anything about OTA provisioning.